# Declaration specifier which consists of the only type-qualifier

Tags: c, language-lawyer, declaration

It is well-defined that `long`, `signed long`, `long int`, or `signed long int` are all specify the same type. Actually, the `N2310/6.7.2(p5)`:

> Each of the comma-separated multisets designates the same type, except
>   that for bit-fields, it is implementation-defined whether the
>   specifier int designates the same type as `signed int` or the same type
>   as `unsigned int`.

So as far as I can tell, the `int` can be simply omitted. Now consider the declaration:

```
const a;
```

`GCC` warns that

```
warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘a’
```

Such declaration is permitted by the grammar since the `declarator` here is an identifier `a`, the `declaration-specifiers` is a type-qualifier `const`. `N2310/6.7(p1)`:

```
declaration:
    declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list opt ;
    [...]
declaration-specifiers:
    [...]
    type-qualifier declaration-specifiers opt
    [...]
```

But looking through the Standard sections `6.7` and `6.7.3` (even no such an example) I could not prove that such a declaration actually implicitly declares the type of `a` to be `const int`.

What type `a` should have in the declaration `const a;` according to the Standard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

6.7.2p2:

> At least one type specifier shall be given in the declaration specifiers in each declaration, and in the specifier-qualifier list in each struct declaration and type name.

`const a;` is invalid.

---

C89/C90 used to default to `int` in these situations, which is why compilers still support it, but "implicit int" was officially removed in C99.

ISO 9899:1990 had the following entry under *6.5.2 Type specifiers*:

> - `int`, `signed`, `signed int`, or no type specifiers

Comment: Nice catch. This "optional" `declaration-specifier` was misleading. Thank you.